# Экранчик общественного транспорта (название)

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это такое? Табло, щит, экранчик?

А также что такое этот экран снаружи автобуса, на котором отображен его номер?

Answer (score 1):

И экран снаружи, и экран внутри называется **табло**. Табло бывает разных видов: переднее, боковое, заднее, салонное. Последнее и изображено на вашей фотографии

Answer (score 0):

На фото непонятно, может бегущая строка.
А может просто - монитор.
Про таблички автобуса: https://vk.com/svetoidea78